# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' in wordpress? woocommerce 3.0

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I just update woocommerce when trying to finalize a request on my site it give the following error. How could I solve this?

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid order.' in /home/educateindia/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/abstract-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php:86 Stack trace: #0 /home/educateindia/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php(143): Abstract_WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT->read(Object(WC_Order)) #1 /home/educateindia/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php(109): WC_Data_Store->read(Object(WC_Order)) #2 /home/educateindia/public_html/wp-content/themes/educate/framework/classes/themex.woo.php(215): WC_Abstract_Order->__construct(2518) #3 /home/educateindia/public_html/wp-content/themes/educate/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php(8): ThemexWoo::getRelatedPost(2518, Array, true) #4 /home/educateindia/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(204): include('/home/educatein...') #5 /home/educateindia/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-sho in /home/educateindia/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/abstract-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php on line 86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I had enabled WooCommerce USPS services plugin. I already had the BASIC Activated. I Deactivated the non-basic plugin, and everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. The problem was solved after deactivating plugin **"WooCommerce Auctions Pro"**